# Argon2 with node docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, nestjs, argon2-ffi

I have NestJs application that works perfectly on my local machine (windows).
Now I would like to create a docker container for my application.
When i try to start my container i have one issue with Argon2.
I install on the container all the argon needs.
where's my mistake?

Thank

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Error loading shared library /usr/src/app/node_modules/argon2/build/Release/argon2.node: Exec format error
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at load (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:20:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/argon2/argon2.js:5:81)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
```

### Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

# --no-cache: download package index on-the-fly, no need to cleanup afterwards
# --virtual: bundle packages, remove whole bundle at once, when done
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python \
    make \
    g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del build-dependencies
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm install argon2
RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.13-alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

# --no-cache: download package index on-the-fly, no need to cleanup afterwards
# --virtual: bundle packages, remove whole bundle at once, when done
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python \
    make \
    g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del build-dependencies
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm install argon2
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

### docker-compose :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  main:
    container_name: NestApp
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      #- /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm run start:dev
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bdd
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that is ignoring your `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Thank you , that solved my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering for posterity sake:

Sounds like you have no `.dockerignore` file so when you `COPY . .` you are pulling over the `node_modules` folder from your local machine (Windows) and trying to run it in Docker (Alpine Linux), so while you correctly run `npm install argon2` in the Docker context, you overwrite it when you copy from local to Docker. If you create a `.dockerignore` file, add `/node_modules` to it so that you don;t move the `node_modules` directory

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue I did the above tip by Jay McDoniel. Although for me I also had another problem that seemed to have thrown the same error. The problem for me was I accidentally `npm install`ed something in my project while using a yarn project where I should have `yarn add`ed this gave a warning that said:

```
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by    
tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid 
resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this. 
warning, remove package-lock.json.
```

The problem wasn't yet fixed until I removed `package-lock.json` (lesson learned: pick your least favorite of the two lockfiles (`yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`) to remove from you project and always keep just one type of package manager in use between `yarn` and `npm`)